# How to connect Oracle database (11G) to visual studio Version 17.5.3?

Tags: database, oracle, visual-studio

I've tried a lot of things seeing youtube videos and all. Tried installing ODAC and oracle developer tools for vs. I can see my tables in visual studios, but the moment I try to connect, it says connection timeout! [In case you wonder what the message in package says: Package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 21.9.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEsM2.png)

I've tried using odac and oracle developer tools for vs 2022, and downloaded packages from nuGet(shown in screenshot).
Just trying to connect my oracle database with my visual studios.

Comment: Why use a 15 year old version of the database that is no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, see [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

You cannot connect with a Oracle 21 Client to an Oracle 11 Database.
You need to use an older client or a newer database.